# SNS handle more than 10 million subscriptions per topic

Tags: push-notification, amazon-sns

how to SNS Topic handle  more than 10 million subscriptions.

Request increase the limit.
is any other option to handle this scenario.

Topic: MyAPPNOTIFICATION
Reached 9.9 Million subscriptions.

Comment: Just to clarify... Are you saying that you have an actual application that needs to send a the same message to 9.9 million subscribers? Are these mobile application users? That seems like an unusually high number.

Comment: yes i need to send a the same message to 9.9+ million subscribers

Answer (score 3):

The 2014 [Amazon SNS Update – Large Topics and MPNS Authenticated Mode](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/sns-large-topics-and-mpns-auth-mode/) blog post from AWS says:

> Today we are lifting the limit of 10,000 subscriptions per SNS topic; you can now create **as many as you need** and no longer need to partition large subscription lists across multiple topics. This has been a frequent request from AWS customers that use SNS to build news and media sharing applications.
>
> There is an **administrative limit of 10 million subscriptions per topic**, but we’ll happily raise it if you expect to have more subscribers for a single topic. Fill out the [Contact Us](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/) form, select SNS, and we’ll take good care of you!